# What is contained in the virtual page of virtual memory?

Tags: memory, architecture, virtual-machine

I am studying virtual memory right now and I am a little confused.

I would assume that virtual memory should only hold addresses to the physical location (HD or memory) of the data to save space, after all virtual memory is used to save space.

What would go inside the virtual page? And what is the offset bits in virtual address used for?

Answer (score 0):

Are you learning architecture organization or a SO specific?
Anyway a virtual page contains that addresses you mentioned and a flag to indicate if the data its pointing to is loaded (in physical memory) or not. If the data is not loaded it generates a "page fault" to the memory manager demandes SO to load that data (and maybe dealocate some physical memory to get enough space to do that).
Also pages can contain a few flags/values used by the memory management system. It depends on the memory strategy adopted (seek round robin and others algorithms).
In relation to the offset there's a dozen modes memory can be addressed (at least for Windows) it depends on the mode used.
Memory management is a large topic and demands some books to be read if you really wants to learn how it works. There a lot a minor details.
If you are just wanting a A+ Try to ask your teacher and ask colleagues previous attended that class about what your teacher is focusing at. That cans ave a lot of effort.